# PhP script not running in server even though it worked in my laptop with same parameters

Tags: php

Hi there again community! hope you are doing well!

I have created a code in my laptop using php ver 7.2 in WAMP server.
The code consist in 2 php files. One has html/php and the other has php/sql.

When I executed the code in my laptop, it runned without any problems. 
When I do the same in my live server, it gives out a run problem. I have tried to solve this but can't seem to find out what it is. It's probably something abvious but since I am new to php and servers, I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Thank you all for your continous help as always!

For privacy reasons I can't give out my html/php code. However I did create a very simple php/sql code that throws the exact same problem.

Here is the php/sql simple code that gives the exact same problem:

```
<?php
    //Gets server connection credentials stored in tempCredentialsFoile.php
    require_once('tempCredentialsFoile.php');

    $command = "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
    $command = "BEGIN";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);

    $Name_Selected = $_POST['name_selected'] ?? '0';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('$Name_Selected')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); //Executes query.

    // The "??" after the POST method is a new function in php v7.2.
    // If by anychance the POST method doesnt receive any input, it automatically 
    // assigns the value that is between the commas. This being the number '0' in my case

    if($result){
        $command = "COMMIT";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);

        echo "<br>Tables have been saved witn 0 errors.";
    } else {
        $command = "ROLLBACK";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);

        echo "<br>Error! Databases could not be saved. <br>";
    }

    $command = "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1"; //return to autocommit
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);

    //Close the sql connection to dababase
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PS: I am using PHP v7.2

EDIT: Here is the image of the error.

[image]

Comment: " gives out a run problem" — What, specifically, does the error say? Is it a MySQL error? Call `mysqli_error` to get the error message.

Comment: What is the error being sent to the browser? Without that, it's hard to know what the problem is

Comment: If you can't show the code it is going to be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: A side remark: "For security reasons I can't give out my html/php code" - that hints at a fundamental missconception about how security works. If you implemented a robust and secure solution then it does not matter if you hand out the code - and you should! Not doing so suggests that you missunderstand obfuscation as security - which it is _not_.

Comment: Please tell us what the http servers error log files contain about this issue. Little sense in trying to debug an issue without that information.

Comment: Maybe he worded incorrectly and it's because of privacy or NDA considerations or something. That said, if the code he did provide has the same error, we should be able to help (provided the OP let's us know what the error he's seeing is) regardless of the underlying code

Comment: You have a typo at `sql = "...` is missing $

Comment: Sorry guys for not posting the error. Ill edit the context and post the image

Comment: Already posted the error it presents.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

Aparently the php version of the server I have at work doesn't accept the new php 7.1 new funtions since it's still in v5.

I am refering to the "?" after the POST methods brackets.

```
 $Name_Selected = $_POST['name_selected'] ?? '0';
```

The "??" after the "]" means that if the post doesnt have a declared value in it when executing, you are going to automatically declare it with the value you have placed in quotation after the "??". In my case it the character 0.

```
 $Name_Selected = $_POST['name_selected'] ?? '0'; <--
```

After eliminating the "??" from the code, it all worked property.